# Probability question: Dice roll

Tags: probability, statistics

The probability of seeing a "1" on one fair die roll is 1/6 (fraction). 
A die is rolled 18 times.  Assume that each roll is independent of all other rolls.  What is the probability of seeing the number "1" exactly 2 times?  Round your answer to 4 decimal places.

Comment: do you know the binomial law?

Comment: Hint: Start your thinking by this possibility:
$x_1,1,x_2,1,x_3, x_4\cdots, x_{18}$, where the $x_i$ stand for "anything else but 1.

Comment: A good question included your own attempts to solve the problem, or at least some discussion on what you do and don't understand about it, so that people can focus on what trouble they might help you with.  Otherwise it merely looks like you want people to do all you own work for you.

Answer (score 3):

Let's count the number of ways we can have exactly two dice rolls be $1$s, then we can divide by the total number of possibilities.

---

We first have to choose the two dice tosses (out of the $18$ tosses) that will show up as $1$s. The number of ways to do this is a [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient):

$$\binom{18}{2} = \frac{18 \cdot 17}{2} = 153$$

Then, we must multiply by the number of ways to choose the values of the other rolls. There are $16$ other rolls and each have $5$ possibilities (they can't be $1$ since we've chosen the two rolls that will be $1$s). The number of ways to choose these values is $$5^{16}$$ 
Finally, we should divide by the number of total possibilities. Since there are $18$ dice rolls and $6$ possibilities for each, this is $6^{18}$. The final probability is therefore

$$\boxed{\frac{153 \cdot 5^{16}}{6^{18}}}$$

Answer (score -2):

$$p={18 \choose 2}(1/6)^2(5/6)^{16}$$

Comment: While this expression is valid for the requested probability (but does not attempt to give the required "rounding"), a more useful Answer would explain how it was arrived at.  This might be little more than mention of the Binomial Thm. but could include a link to more detailed explanation of that famous result.

Comment: Ok if it is more useful for you. Good luck with that...